# Hidden chips - how to handle when a player goes all in and chips were hidden

Tags: rules, poker-strategy

Cash game poker night in america
[hand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wivSoxwaPXM&t=389s)

This hand was over a year ago with Alec Torelli

Recently Doug Polk posted on his channel with some creative editing

Alec had two 5K that are hidden from the dealer and every player but the player to his right.

```
SB   25
BB   50 
UTG 100 straddle   alec  AKo
Mid 200 straddle 
Co  575            tilly JTo
Btn 575 call       wolf  ATo

SB  575 call             AJs
BB  fold 
UTG 2825 
Mid fold 
CO  fold 
Mid all-in for like 25K   
Btn fold 

SB  fold  
UTG call
```

This is where it get interesting. Mid thought he was playing for $15K and he is really playing for $25K because chips were hidden. He did not ask for a count. He said he would not have pushed if he knew the count. He had ATo. He is kind stuck as he knows he is probably beat and the bigger bet is more likely to get a fold.  He also could be on AA KK wanting to look weak.

It was not clear if PNIA would even let them cut a deal.

One of the points made is it would not be fair to the folds as they might have played if the bet was 15K. One had AJs. Up till now it is not clear if the floor / PNIA will even let them cut a deal. Floor said if I rule it would be all in.

One of the other players said to the floor you need to make a ruling here and called the clock.

Floor quickly ruled all in stands.

UTG with AQo calls and wins a big pot

Was that the correct ruling?

Secondary was it correct play?

Secondary was Alec angle shooting?

Answer (score 1):

Will not accept my own answer.

Yes I think the floor made the correct call.

I think Alec was careless if not reckless in having chips hidden. They were not hidden from him - not like he did not know they were hidden.  Do I think he was angling?  No, but he should not have let that situation happen.  He is a pro and coach.

**Play**

When Alec raised to 2825 he still had to get through 5 players. It was not a bluff. I would put AQo on the bottom of his range here.  And he could be on a monster.

If Wolf wanted to bluff the pot then why not raise the first pass to like 2500.  He still has a good hand and position.

ATo the second pass needed to get through 2 and Alec was getting 1.56:1 to call.    Push without getting a count was sloppy.  And it makes it look bluffy in my opinion. ATo is not great but I think it is too good of a hand to bluff in this spot in position.  Think of it as a strong T.

If Wolf was super strong like AA, KK, QQ, AKs in position he should have just called the second round or raised the first round.

When Wolf claimed he did not see those chips and would not have done it if he had known tells me that he is weak or he is super strong and wants a call. When he does not ask to pull back the 10K it makes me more put him on super strong. But again that is strange betting for super strong.

I personally think Alec would have been better off taking the 10K back and out of play to reduce his risk and call.  Even if he is ahead

Comment: Another video was release that showed detail of all chip movement by Alec and I am more leaning to it might be intentional.